# Assign content of a file to an array in bash

Tags: bash, sh

I have a file that contains parts of file names either as newline (or separated by spaces). Lets take the following example:

```
cat file.txt
1
4
500
```

The actual file names are `file_1.dat, file_2.dat, file_3.dat, file_4.dat file_500.dat`, and so on.

I want to combine only those files whose names (or part of the names) are stored in `file.txt`.

To do so I am doing the following:

```
 ## read the file and assign to an array
 array=()
 while IFS= read -r line; do
 array+=($line)
 done < file.txt

 ## combine the contents of the files
 for file in ${array[@]}
  do
  cat "file_$file.dat"
  done > output.dat
```

Now in this solution what I don't like is the assignment of the array, that I have to run a `do` loop for this.

I tried to use

```
 mapfile -t array < <(cat file.txt)
```

I also tried,

```
 array=( $(cat file2.txt) )
```

The array that is needed finally is

```
array=(1 4 500)
```

In some of the answers(in this platform), I see that doing in the above way (the last option) might be harmful. I wanted to have some clarification on what to do for such assignments.

**My question is: in this situation what is the best (safe and fast) way to assign the content of a file into an array?**

Comment: Be precise: Do you expect each array element to contain one **line** of the file, or one **word** of the file. We can't see this from your example.

Comment: @user1934428 I suppose all of these methods work. But particularly the last one I realize I can simply do `array=( ( cat file.txt) )` without making the input file as a row. What I want to know is if the third way of assigning is okay and safe.
The array should be `array=( 1 4 500 )` which it takes from the `file.txt` file.

Comment: Basically, I want to avoid the use of any `do` loops which makes the code slower (even in the case where I `cat` those files).

Comment: This really is not an answer to what I asked ....

Comment: @user1934428  The array should be `array=( 1 4 500 )`  which it takes from the `file.txt` file. So yes, it's every line of the file.

Comment: Perhaps you could include this information to your question.

Comment: `mapfile -t array < file.txt` should be sufficient. What was it about your attempts that failed?

Comment: @Boogeyman : Your assignment `array=( $(cat file2.txt) )` would assign every word to one array element. The `mapfile` approach does not yield anything useful for my platform (which is Cygwin), but this could be a flaw in the Cygwin implementation of bash. At least you would have to set `IFS´ to a newline, to have the inplut being split at line boundaries.

Comment: @user1934428 , agree. I have edited this. `array=( $(cat file.txt) )`  should do the assignment of each line to each array element.

Comment: @chepner, it does not fail.  All of them work. I was particularly asking about the last option `array=( $(cat file2.txt) )` if it is `safe` since I read in some of the questions that people like to use either `do` loop or `mapfile`.

Comment: It's safe *here*, but not in general. Consider a file that has lines with multiple whitespace-separated words. It fails for such files, and provides no benefit over `mapfile` when it does work.

Comment: Strive to write code that works even on unexpected input.

Comment: at the beginning you state: *file that contains parts of file names either as newline (or separated by spaces)* but then only provide examples of newline-delimited values; please update the question with some sample data that is 'separated by spaces' and an example of a matching filename; once you've added such an example, run your different pieces of code again and see which ones break and which ones still 'work'; hint: after populating an array run `typeset -p array` to see the contents of the array; one more question/item ... can a filename (in your environment) include white space

Comment: If your question is about building the array, why mention `cat` at all?  If your question is about displaying the files, why build an array at all?  The question seems like it could be trimmed down a bit.

Comment: @markp-fuso, William Pursell, I understood the point. The problem might come in the second scenario where the file has entries separated by spaces. I have removed unnecessary parts of the question for clarity.

Comment: If a line in the file contains a space, do you want it to generate 2 entries in the array or a single entry with a space?

Comment: @WilliamPursell In that case I would have wanted each line in each array entry. 
And probably as @chepner has also pointed out `mapfile`   or `readarray` would be the safer option.

Answer (score 5):

```
array=( $(cat file2.txt) )
```

does not necessarily put each *line* in the array. It puts each *word* resulting from word-splitting and globbing into the array.

Consider this file

```
1
2 3
*
```

`mapfile -t array < file.txt` will create an array with the elements `1`, `2 3`, and `*`.

`array=( $(cat file.txt) )` will create an array with the elements `1`, `2`, and `3`, along with an element for each file name in the current directory.

Using `mapfile` is both safer and makes your intent of storing one line per element clearer.

However, there is no need for an array at all. You can process each file as you pull a line from your input file.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    cat "file_$line.dat"
done < file.txt > output.dat
```

Comment: `array=($(<file2.txt))` (No cats or dogs were harmed in this example.)

Comment: The `$(<...)` makes no difference, because it's the wrong way to create the array in the first place.

Comment: Indeed, it makes no difference in terms of correctness. I just like to point out unnecessary extra processes (mostly `cat`) when I spot them.

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t want to deduplicate the file name fragments:

```sh
readarray -t lines < file.txt
declare -a fragments
for line in "${lines[@]}"; do
  fragments+=($line)
done
names=("${fragments[@]/#/file_}")
names=("${names[@]/%/.dat}")
cat "${names[@]}"
```

If you **do** want to deduplicate the file name fragments:

```sh
readarray -t lines < file.txt
declare -Ai set_of_fragments
for line in "${lines[@]}"; do
  for fragment in $line; do
    ((++set_of_fragments["${fragment}"]))
  done
done
fragments=("${!set_of_fragments[@]}")
names=("${fragments[@]/#/file_}")
names=("${names[@]/%/.dat}")
cat "${names[@]}"
```